# Why does docker image grow so fast after installing sudo?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a local docker image based on oracle linux for installing oracle database. This is more a docker question that a DB question.

There are some fairly large data files (~12GB).

Normally when I do a docker commit it increases the size of the image slightly with anything newly added.

I installed sudo on the machine and all of a sudden every time I commit the image it starts doubling the size of the image (12GB->24GB->50GB).

I guess I can find ways to live without sudo but does anyone have a guess why merely running "yum install sudo" as root would cause this huge image size? Im at a loss what other details to provide.

Nothing fancy in the docker commit:

```
docker commit my-container the-image:v1
```

I've gone through the entire image with **du -sh** and there are no additional data files that would explain the size.

I do have some mount points and volumes but those should not be included in the image from what I can tell and even if they are the image size ends up bigger than the sum of volumes.

Any chance its writing swap space to the image? I have the database shut down and no idea what that would have to do with sudo command being installed or not.

Comment: What are the exact steps I need to run to reproduce the exact image you're using now?  Using `docker commit` isn't generally a best practice since it leads to images that are hard to reproduce.  You also don't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all, since you can always switch to `USER root` in your Dockerfile to do things like install software.

Comment: oracle database wont start as root unfortunately. I found a workaround I can use su directly.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the following instead of sudo. Essentially there is an entrypoint script that has to extract a tar with the database bits (into a docker volume). I was having some permission issues extracting the data. It seems like maybe docker always changes the owner of a volume to root and I needed it to be user oracle. Anyway I added this in my script and its working fine:

```
echo "myRootPassword" | su -c "chown oracle:oinstall /ORCL" root
```

I guess I am still curious why adding sudo causes this issue but not curious to waste any more time on it.

- You can replicate it by running a base image from ubuntu.
- commit the base image to a second image
- Then run and ssh into the second image and install sudo.
- Lastly commit the image to a 3rd image. The third image image is like 1GB bigger than the second image.

Comment: It's hard to believe that merely having `sudo` installed would have the stated effect without a reproducer we can run ourselves. A [mre] is really called for in the question -- to let others easily reproduce the stated behavior -- if you want an explanation.

Comment: (Also, details of the Docker installation matter -- what will make a Docker install using overlayfs blow up its disk usage is different from what will do that for a Docker install using a block-level disk overlay backend rather than a file-level one)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the images get layered when you do a commit. Some times it seems like the commits create a slightly larger image and some times it must take the previous image and add the current image (12g+12g). I guess this has nothing to do with sudo after all - I just happened to keep adding sudo at the wrong time so it seemed related.

The issue is Im trying to build a database image and its very hard to do it all in 1 Docker file. So I was creating a base image and running the oracle install in the running container using x11 forwarding. Oracle DB installation is a pain to figure out in silent mode and Ive spent the last full day trying to get the response file correct. Anyway closing this issue as its nothing to do with sudo.